# FullCalendar - All events display in one day

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm making ASP NET MVC project in c# and I would like to use FullCalendar to do schedule for workers.
When I create a new event, it always writes on the same day but the dates in the database are correct. I don't know where I am making the error or how to fix it.

My FullCalendar code is:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Schedule/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                eventID: v.EventID,
                                title: v.Worker,
                                description: v.Description,
                                start: moment(v.Start),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                                allDay: v.IsFullDay
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })
            }

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: false,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        selectedEvent = calEvent;
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function (start, end) {
                        selectedEvent = {
                            eventID: 0,
                            title: '',
                            description: '',
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: false,
                            color: ''
                        };
                        openAddEditForm();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                            EventID: event.eventID,
                            Worker: event.title,
                            Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                            End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                            Description: event.description,
                            ThemeColor: event.color,
                            IsFullDay: event.allDay
                        };
                        SaveEvent(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                //Open modal dialog for edit event
                openAddEditForm();
            })
            $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Schedule/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            $('#dtp1,#dtp2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
            });

            $('#chkIsFullDay').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#divEndDate').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#divEndDate').show();
                }
            });

            function openAddEditForm() {
                if (selectedEvent != null) {
                    $('#hdEventID').val(selectedEvent.eventID);
                    $('#txtWorker').val(selectedEvent.title);
                    $('#txtStart').val(selectedEvent.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'));
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').prop("checked", selectedEvent.allDay || false);
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').change();
                    $('#txtEnd').val(selectedEvent.end != null ? selectedEvent.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : '');
                    $('#txtDescription').val(selectedEvent.description);
                    $('#ddThemeColor').val(selectedEvent.color);
                }
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModalSave').modal();
            }

            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                //Validation/
                if ($('#txtWorker').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Worker required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Start date required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('End date required');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    if (startDate > endDate) {
                        alert('Invalid end date');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                    Worker: $('#txtWorker').val().trim(),
                    Start: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                    End: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                    Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                    ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                    IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
                }
                SaveEvent(data);
                // call function for submit data to the server
            })

            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Schedule/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    </script>
```

Controller:

```cs
public class ScheduleController : Controller
{
    // GET: Schedule
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (EventsEn dc = new EventsEn())
        {
            var events = dc.Events.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (EventsEn dc = new EventsEn())
        {
            if (e.EventID > 0)
            {
                //Update the event
                var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    v.Worker = e.Worker;
                    v.Start = e.Start;
                    v.End = e.End;
                    v.Description = e.Description;
                    v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
                    v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dc.Events.Add(e);
            }

            dc.SaveChanges();
            status = true;

        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (EventsEn dc = new EventsEn())
        {
            var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                dc.Events.Remove(v);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
}
```

And results looks: [image: Fullcalendear View]

but In my database all dates are correct.
[image]
Where is error?

Comment: You know it's really inefficient to destroy and rebuild the calendar every time you just want to update the events? Fullcalendar provides a better way to allow you to refresh the events only, without re-creating the whole calendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents

Comment: Anyway, about your question. Tell me something... what is the data type of the `Start` and `End` columns in your database? Are they `datetime`, or `varchar`?